# Java OutOfMemoryError when VM is set to 1024m max

Tags: java, out-of-memory

An int array of 100 million ints should be 400 MB, right?
One int = 4 bytes

So if I set the VM to have a max heap of 1024m with -Xmx1024m why does this code fail:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] b = new int[100000000]; //100 mil = 400mb
    System.out.println("ok");
    int[] c = new int[100000000];

}
```

This is the output:

```
ok
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

**Solution** - break it up!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = new int[50000000]; //50 mil = 200mb
    System.out.println("ok 1");
    int[] b = new int[50000000];
    System.out.println("ok 2");
    int[] c = new int[50000000];
    System.out.println("ok 3");
    int[] d = new int[50000000];
    System.out.println("ok 4");


}
```

Comment: this may not be an answer but can you use getObjectSize()  method of Instrumentation  interface? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getObjectSize%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: An `int` holds 32 bits of data, but that doesn't mean it only takes up 4 bytes in whatever JVM you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that when you're creating this int[], it requires contiguous memory of 400mb. Basically this means, you need a solid block of 400mb of memory for use. Due to fragmentation of the heap, it can't find a solid 400mb block of memory to use. That's why you're getting the out of memory error in this situation.

Comment: Surely, you're not suggesting the heap starts up in a fragmented state :-)

Comment: Ah! Solution put into question since I can't correctly format this comment!